# Torsion free modules, free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

This particular question was asked in my Abstract Algebra Exam and I couldn't solve it in examination hall. Now, I thought I should try it again but I was unable to.

> Prove that every free module  F over an arbitrary integral domain with identity is torsion-free but the  converse is false.

Module is given free means that a basis set exists (say X).To prove that it is Torsional free i need to show that every element except identity has infinite order OR Assuming it to  be not torsional free and then proving that it can't be free module.

Let $f \in F$. Then I am at loss of ideas how it doesn't have any non-identity element of finite order.

On the other hand, let converse holds. So, Every torsion-free module over an arbitrary integral domain is free. But what is the contradiction here?

I am at loss of ideas over this and would very much appreciate help.

Comment: hi user319735, it is certainly possible for torsion-free modules to have elements of finite order; for example, consider the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ as a module over itself. for an integral domain $R$, what it means for an $R$-module $M$ to be torsion-free is that $rm=0$ implies $m=0$ for all $r\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and $m\in M$. if $R=\mathbb{Z}$, then this is the same as requiring that every non-zero element of $M$ have infinite order, but the conditions do not coincide in general

Answer (score 1):

Every free module over an arbitrary integral domain with identity is torsion-free.

Let $F$ be such a D-module, where $D$ is an integral domain, i.e. $D$ is commutative, has identity, and no non-zero divisors. 
By Characterization of free D-modules ( any $R$-modules with identity actually ), $F$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of the D-modules $D$ , say : $$F\cong \oplus_{i\in I} D$$
Then any element $x$ of $F$ that is not the neutral element can be identified with $\phi(x)= \sum_{i\in I} d_i\neq 0$ where the $d_i\in D$ ( and at least one of the $d_i$'s is not zero ), and for any $r\in D: $ $r\phi(x)= r(\sum_{i\in I} d_i)= \sum_{i\in I} rd_i= 0 \implies rd_i=0 \ \forall i\in I$ ( the former zero is the zero of the direct sum ) thus as $D$ has no zero divisors : $$r\phi(x)= 0\ \implies  \forall i\in I:\ r= 0 \ or\ d_i= 0\ \implies r=0 $$ ( as we established one of the $d_i$'s at least is non zero )

This means that $\phi(x)$ has an infinite order hence as $\phi$ was our isomorphism also $x$ must have infinite order as desired.

The converse is false, think about an example of a torsion free module over $Z$ (an integral domain) which is not free.

Comment: What is $\phi $ here in 3rd para of your answer , Specifically:" Then any element x of F that is not the neutral element can be identified with $\phi(x)= ...$?